# Is there a way to make postgres "COUNT WHERE" query log(N)?

Tags: postgresql, index, database-internals

Afaik, now this request `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE rating > 50` looks like this:

1. find an item with the value of rating 50(or greater) in our b-tree index, pretty fast.
2. Iterate though all items which are on the right.

Am I right? If yes, why don't postgres store number of items in each node so we can skip the second step making the request incredibly fast? If no, why are they so slow?

And is there any way to have an index for counts or something to make request as fast as looking for a single item in binary tree?

Comment: How would you store a count in the face of concurrent changes that need to be atomic and isolated?

Comment: @jjanes, use some kind of lock?

Comment: A lock for the duration of the transaction?  That is going to be a devastating loss of concurrency.

Comment: @jjanes, another option is to get the count as is, despite of sometimes we're going to get wrong values.